# How do I align an anchor point to the centre of a line or object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

There's probably a really simple answer but I can't work it out. If I use the pen tool to make an anchor point somewhere along a line, how do I get that anchor point into the exact centre of said line?

Comment: based on your comments is your line in fact a curve?

Answer (score 2):

if your line is straight, use Object->Path->Add Anchor Points

Comment: Ah, the line isn't straight. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the **Align** window/tab, on the Align window/tab go to **Distribute Anchor points** and click **Horizontal distribute center**. Make sure the **Align to selection** option is selected.
[image: http://imgur.com/D231yuf]

If you are working with a straight line with just 3 anchors you need a to add an extra 4th anchor temporarily to get the distribute to work properly. Select the the first, second(center), and third anchor with direct selection tool, then click the **Horizontal distribute center** button to center the second anchor between the first and third. You can now delete the fourth.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's not clear cut answer, its all relative to what kind of line/object your working with.

Options (similar question on the [adobe form](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/976088?start=0&tstart=0)):

1. Use [Guides, Grids, and/or rulers](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rulers-grids-guides-crop-marks.html) to align the object(s)/point(s). ([Custom guides](http://youtu.be/WDrKhAkRCzE))
2. [Mirror/Reflect](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rotating-reflecting-objects.html) the object(s)/point(s)
3. Use Align and Distribute Tools:

   - [Align to key object](http://www.lynda.com/Illustrator-tutorials/How-use-Align-Key-Object-Illustrator/117542/161739-4.html)
   - [Alignment and Distribute](http://youtu.be/kOQ0fnOtkXY)

You may have to use multiple options to get your given task done.

Answer (score 1):

For lines,

1. Select the line
2. With the pen tool hover over the line till you see the 'intersect' label appear
3. Press on '+' on the keyboard that converts the Pen tool to Add Anchor Point tool and click on the 'intersect' point indicated.

This will add an anchor point at the center of the line.