# How to create a node at the exact midpoint of a segment in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I have created a path that is a line segment. It only has two endpoint nodes. How do I create a new node at the exact midpoint of the segment? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I align an anchor point to the centre of a line or object?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42151/how-do-i-align-an-anchor-point-to-the-centre-of-a-line-or-object)

Comment: If you have smart guides on, your mouse can snap to the center of a segment line and say "intersect" then you can manually add an anchor point.

Comment: @AndrewH - the question is for Inkscape, not Illustrator.

Comment: See this related answer which I posted today: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/144500/inkscape-dash-stroke-and-mid-marker/144510#144510 - it contains instructions for doing exactly that.  Read the section that starts with "If you already drew a line . . ."